# Does Ionic Community version support Live update aka 'New version available' notifications?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native

Does Ionic Community version support Live update aka 'New version available' notifications?
On their side by side comparison page, Community version doesn't support Live Updates.

[image: Ionic Plans]

[Ionic Plans](https://dashboard.ionicframework.com/account-setup?loc=billing)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Ionic Community is a paid version including support for many things as deploy, publish and so on... It facilitates a lot, there are a service also that you can do a [Live Update](https://ionic.io/docs/appflow/deploy/intro) on your app without the users need go to the Stores. And, you can do this approach by yourself. Just take a look on this tutorial: [Using Direct Update in Cordova and Ionic applications](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/direct-update/). If needed, you can adapt this tutorial related to the Ionic version you are using. You can add push Notification anytime you want.